# Addition statements along with stored procedures

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have written a program block like:

```
DECLARE
  recCount pls_integer:=0;
  idCounter pls_integer:=0;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(value) into recCount FROM classname_ WHERE value='CONNECT_BLOG_INTERPRETER';
  SELECT MAX(classnameid)+1 into idCounter FROM classname_;
  IF recCount = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO classname_ (classnameid, value) values (idCounter, 'CONNECT_BLOG_INTERPRETER');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Inserting Record CONNECT_BLOG_INTERPRETER');
  ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Record CONNECT_BLOG_INTERPRETER already exists.');
  END IF;
END;
```

This statement executes without any problem, but if I wish to execute addition statements with it like:

```
select * from emp;
```

This gives me error like:

```
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 14, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" 
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

But now, I need this to work together. Lets consider the case of DB-Patching, where multiple statements are executed one after the other.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution.

Its just about seperating 2 statements with `/`. This solved the issue.

So now, the final query can work together happily:

```
DECLARE
  recCount pls_integer:=0;
  idCounter pls_integer:=0;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(value) into recCount FROM classname_ WHERE value='CONNECT_BLOG_INTERPRETER';
  SELECT MAX(classnameid)+1 into idCounter FROM classname_;
  IF recCount = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO classname_ (classnameid, value) values (idCounter, 'CONNECT_BLOG_INTERPRETER');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Inserting Record CONNECT_BLOG_INTERPRETER');
  ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Record CONNECT_BLOG_INTERPRETER already exists.');
  END IF;
END;

/

select * from emp;
```